# Unable to delete circle in tDocu layer in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-layers, mounting-holes

I am making a revision to my PCB board where the initial mounting holes were too large and therefore decreasing their size.

The holes are on the Dimension layer (20) and were created using the circle tool, located near the bottom of the left column and pictured below. When decreasing the dimension or deleting the holes completely, a circle of the original size still remains which is on the tDocu layer (51). I am unable to select it and therefore I am unable to remove it.

[image: Circle tool]

Is there a way to delete this circle which is present in the tDocu layer? It does not affect my board design as it is not included when manufactured, however it may cause confusion at a later point.

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Prior to deletion of the circle]

This is what it looks like prior to deletion.

[image: Deletion of the circle]

This is the remaining tDocu circle.

[image: Selection of the region]

This is the result when trying to select the region.

Comment: Going to be tough to help without the actual brd file to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's part of the part ARDUINOR3-BPLACE, which you can select by choosing the bottom left corner of the board and clicking properties. You can fix this in a few ways. The one I would recommend is using the exp-lbrs.ulp to generate a library from the board, modifying the resultant ARDUINOR3-BPLACE library part and then replacing the same part in your design with the modified library part.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. A blind hole which were the remains of a leaded part I had deleted.  Hole was on the dimension layer. Could not delete the hole, could not even highlight or select, move, nothing.  I placed a new, slightly larger hole (using the hole menu) over the existing hole. Then when I deleted the new hole, the original hole was removed.  Quite frustrating but fixed. Easy.